# Segmentation fault accessing array member inside a function using double pointer argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

This is a very basic question, and I think I'm still misunderstanding something very basic.. In my work, I'm trying to use a code someone else wrote in the past and seeing an error I'm having trouble to solve.
Below is the code. I get error in function Partition2. in line `float pivot = arr[left][0];`. I tried `float pivot = *(*(arr+left)+0);` but it's the same. I know `arr` is of type float[300][1]. How can I use the function with smallest modification?

in test.c

```
#define post_nms_topN 300
float unit_bbox_pred[post_nms_topN][4];
float unit_cls_prob[post_nms_topN][1];
...
main()
{
...
    QuickSort2((float **)unit_cls_prob,0,post_nms_topN-1,(float **)unit_bbox_pred);
..
}
```

in QuickSort2.c

```
...
int Partition2(float **arr, int left, int right, float **prop)
{
    float pivot = arr[left][0];   // <=== seg. fault
    //float pivot = *(*(arr+left)+0);

    int low = left+1;
    int high = right;

    while(low <= high)   
    {
        while(pivot <= arr[low][0] && low <= right)
            low++;

        while(pivot >= arr[high][0] && high >= (left+1))
            high--;

        if(low <= high)    
            Swap2(arr, low, high, prop);    
    }
    Swap2(arr, left, high, prop);
    return high;
}

void QuickSort2(float **arr, int left, int right, float **prop)
{
    int pivot;
    if(left <= right)
    {
        pivot = Partition2(arr, left, right, prop); 
        QuickSort2(arr, left, pivot-1, prop);
        QuickSort2(arr, pivot+1, right, prop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Two-dimensional arrays are not equivalent to pointers-to-pointers.  Note that even one-dimensional arrays are not really equivalent to pointers, though the names of a one-dimensional array will act like pointer to the elements in most cases. The names of two-dimensional arrays will act like a pointer to a one-dimensional array in most cases (but *not* like pointers-to-pointers).

Comment: Remove the the cast and fix the code until it compiles quietly without.

Answer (score 2):

> I think I'm still misunderstanding something very basic

Indeed. Pointer-to-pointers are not 2D arrays, nor can they be used to point at 2D arrays. This is a common misunderstanding, because we can often use a regular pointer in place of a 1D array. We would get a pointer to the first element. Yet an array is not a pointer, see [Is an array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

The first element of a 2D array is an array, and not a single item. You cannot set a pointer-to-pointer to point there, because a pointer-to-pointer could only be used against *an array of pointers*, which is something entirely different.

As for how to fix your function, see [Ways to pass 2D Array to function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522341/ways-to-pass-2d-array-to-function-in-c). There's a code example as well as a more in-depth explanation about how arrays "decay" when used as function parameters.